# Sorting on directorySearcher based on two properties in c#

Tags: c#, sorting, ldap, directoryentry, directorysearcher

I'm trying to get a sorted `SearchResultCollection` object based on department, and then by name (both alphabetical). I'm trying to load two properties, but this merely takes the last property specified and sorts it based on that.

My current code is the following:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAP"]);
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
{
    SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
    Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(physicalDeliveryOfficeName=Dartmouth))"
};
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("phone");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("email");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department");

search.Sort.Direction = System.DirectoryServices.SortDirection.Ascending;
search.Sort.PropertyName = "department";
search.Sort.PropertyName = "name";

SearchResultCollection result = search.FindAll();
```

But again, this only sorts by name. I need all users grouped by department, and from there sorted by name.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `SearchResultCollection` to an `IEnumerable` and then sort with a custom `IComparer` that you develop

```
var results = search.FindAll().Cast<SearchResult>()
                              .Sort(/*your IComparer<SearchResult>*/);
```

Sort the results on client side because server side sorts in AD are resource intensive.

*In addition - if you have AD 2000 it doesn't support search on more than one attribute*

Comment: Just as a question, does AD 2008 supprt search on more than one attribute?

Comment: @JonathanPrall - am... I don't really know but I would avoid the sorting on the AD server - better "waste" that computing power on your side which is probably less busy.

Comment: @JonathanPrall - BTW - did the answer solve your issue?